# Commits don't appear on gitlab

Tags: git, github, gitlab, command-line-interface

I did some work locally --> git add --> git commit --> git push origin master, where master is a forked repo of an upstream master:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://gitlab.my-company/me/repo-name.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.my-company/me/repo-name.git (push)
upstream        https://gitlab.my-company/team/repo-name.git (fetch)
upstream        https://gitlab.my-company/team/repo-name.git (push)
```

When I git push origin master, the result in my git bash terminal looks successful enough:

```
$ git push origin master
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://gitlab.my-company/me/repo-name.git
   5bacf635..fbdfebe7  master -> master
```

However when I visit my fork, there's no evidence of my work in the master.  The latest commit is a week old.

I've tried pushing to new branches on my origin.  (e.g., git push origin splash).  When I do, I get the following error: src refspec splash does not match any.  AND, while the branches do get created in GitLab, the work in the branches doesn't reflect any of the new work I've done.  (Again, the newest commit appears a week old).

One possible helpful factor is I've noticed I did the work on a weird feature branch locally that I didn't mean to use.  However I don't see how that's an issue.

This jpeg summarizes our general workflow:
[image: My general workflow]

Any clues????

Here is git log:

```
 $ git log
    commit b6c2beb9e8f94a4f104a471a0edc9b8fbc7bea2e (HEAD -> activeDirectory, origin/activeDirectory)
    Author: Mike Lastname <mike@myemail.com>
    Date:   Tue Sep 25 08:31:17 2018 -0700

        debug version control this is a test

    commit 9d0c32af97f8757b2c352f70ac4d47d32ea2100e
    Author: Mike Lastname <mike@myemail.com>
    Date:   Tue Sep 25 07:59:18 2018 -0700

        update title from TDS Server to API

    commit e80d98113d55b2eec5a84a675b3e6dd99937ed67
    Author: Mike Lastname <mike@myemail.com>
    Date:   Tue Sep 25 07:48:32 2018 -0700

        add hostname endpoint to server to support client request for server name

    commit c721eec34b31470b458dbbc76ca0c42a8a5ecfd4
    Author: Mike Lastname <mike@myemail.com>
    Date:   Tue Sep 25 07:46:13 2018 -0700

        update App.jsx to request hostname and display it using componentWillMount

    commit 765abfe0c8cbfd243c83558237b311e1c85b2727
    Author: Mike Lastname <mike@myemail.com>
    Date:   Tue Sep 25 07:45:09 2018 -0700

        add bundle.js to gitignore

    commit fbdfebe7299c3c99b930b1b3ada2f5ebd28f4fbe (upstream/master, origin/solution, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
    Merge: f563a96f 16069b7c
    Author: Grant b <bob.b@myemail.com>
    Date:   Thu Sep 20 19:18:27 2018 -0700

        Merge branch 'master' into 'master'

        adjusting date incrementer function

        See merge request SA-SM/repo-name!18

    commit 16069b7c9e6f819e7bf3f9e38bb37f89d81a1c37
    Author: bob b <chq-bobb@corp.myemail.com>
    Date:   Thu Sep 20 19:17:09 2018 -0700

    :...skipping...
    commit b6c2beb9e8f94a4f104a471a0edc9b8fbc7bea2e (HEAD -> activeDirectory, origin/activeDirectory)
    Author: Mike Lastname <mike@myemail.com>
    Date:   Tue Sep 25 08:31:17 2018 -0700

        debug version control this is a test

    commit 9d0c32af97f8757b2c352f70ac4d47d32ea2100e
    Author: Mike Lastname <mike@myemail.com>
    Date:   Tue Sep 25 07:59:18 2018 -0700

        update title from TDS Server to API

    commit e80d98113d55b2eec5a84a675b3e6dd99937ed67
    Author: Mike Lastname <mike@myemail.com>
    Date:   Tue Sep 25 07:48:32 2018 -0700

        add hostname endpoint to server to support client request for server name

    commit c721eec34b31470b458dbbc76ca0c42a8a5ecfd4
    Author: Mike Lastname <mike@myemail.com>
    Date:   Tue Sep 25 07:46:13 2018 -0700

        update App.jsx to request hostname and display it using componentWillMount

    commit 765abfe0c8cbfd243c83558237b311e1c85b2727
    Author: Mike Lastname <mike@myemail.com>
    Date:   Tue Sep 25 07:45:09 2018 -0700

        add bundle.js to gitignore

    commit fbdfebe7299c3c99b930b1b3ada2f5ebd28f4fbe (upstream/master, origin/solution, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
    Merge: f563a96f 16069b7c
    Author: bob b <bob.b@myemail.com>
    Date:   Thu Sep 20 19:18:27 2018 -0700

        Merge branch 'master' into 'master'

        adjusting date incrementer function

        See merge request SA-SM/repo-name!18

    commit 16069b7c9e6f819e7bf3f9e38bb37f89d81a1c37
    Author: bob b <chq-grantb@corp.myemail.com>
    Date:   Thu Sep 20 19:17:09 2018 -0700

        adjusting date incrementer function
    :
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's your output for `git -log`?

Comment: @Aquarthur, see output in body of question.  Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm, I have no real clue about why it's not working. Any reason why you're `git pull --rebase`ing rather than simply creating a new feature branch and creating a merge request when your code is ready?

Comment: try `git ls-remote` and compare hashes on those branches with output of `git branch --all -vv` - not sure if it helps but can give you another clue

Comment: @Aquarthur no, I honestly need to be more disciplined about doing my work on feature branches.  But I suspect that's a separate matter from this problem?

Comment: @PetrKozelka Thank you I'll try that.